# Posting data to a SQL Server 2008 database from web service yields error

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to use c# to post data to a web service (that I wrote). This web service runs fine when I run it from my local machine. As soon as I move to it a server (within my building), it throws this error:

> Server was unable to process request.
>   ---> ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

I have checked:

- app pool identity - network service

  section enables configuration 
                  of the security authentication mode used by 
                  ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
              -->
              
               section enables configuration 
                  of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
                  during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
                  it enables developers to configure html error pages 
                  to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

  ```
          <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
              <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
              <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
          </customErrors>
          -->
          <pages>
              <controls>
                  <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                  <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
              </controls>
          </pages>
          <httpHandlers>
              <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
              <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
              <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
              <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
          </httpHandlers>
          <httpModules>
              <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
          </httpModules>
      </system.web>
      <system.codedom>
          <compilers>
              <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                  <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                  <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
              </compiler>
          </compilers>
      </system.codedom>
      <!-- 
          The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
          Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
      -->
      <system.webServer>
          <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
          <modules>
              <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
              <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
          </modules>
          <handlers>
              <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
              <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
              <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
              <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
              <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
              <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
              <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
          </handlers>
      </system.webServer>
      <runtime>
          <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
              <dependentAssembly>
                  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
              </dependentAssembly>
              <dependentAssembly>
                  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
              </dependentAssembly>
          </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
  </configuration>
  ```

Comment: Did you set the connection string, and is it the correct one?

Comment: If you're using Integrated Security in the connection string you may well have to change it to use an SQL login (User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
Trusted_Connection=False;)

Comment: What kind of web service? ASMX? WCF? If WCF: how is it hosted? IIS or self-hosting? Show us the relevant config file!!

Answer (score 2):

`Connection property has not been initialized` is usually thrown by the `Connection` object due to `ConnectionString` that was not supplied or incorrect information.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
{
    // don't forget this line.
    connection.ConnectionString = "valid connection string here";
    // then pass the connection to your command object
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
    {
         command.Connection = connection;
         // other codes
    }
}
```

Additional Note:

**[SQL Server 2008 Connection Strings formats...](http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)**

Comment: The connection string is specified in the code.  The server it is being placed on is a local (intranet) server.  I would rather use trusted connection security, but might shift to sql authentication if I cant resolve this issue.  marc_s it is a asmx

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the connection has not been associated with the command object.

Check and see if there's a problem creating the connection object.  Is it properly initialized?  Is it using a correct connection string?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem.  I was actually authenticating to the wrong server.  So once I pointed to the right server, it worked.  Cockpit trouble here.